# Reading in multiple sheets, appending new data, and vlookups from those sheets in R?

Tags: r, excel, automation, tidyverse, vlookup

I am trying to automate a report that we do in excel with R. I have an excel sheet that contains 10 sheets. Of those 10 sheets, I need to update 7 of those sheets with the latest data of the week. Also within those 7 sheets, there are 4 sheets that utilize 6-16 columns with vlookup formulas. The vlookup formulas are pulling data from all these sheets.

So far I have read in the entire excel file with all the sheets with the following code

```
file <- "C:\Users\JSmith\Desktop\data.xlsx"

df <- xlsx_cells(file)
```

I also attempted to tidy this data up once it was read in with the following code

```
df2 <- df %>% select(sheet,character, numeric, date, row, col, data_type)


df91 <- df2 %>% 
  behead("N", 'header_row') %>%
  behead('W', 'row_name') %>%
  select(sheet, row_name, header_row, numeric) %>%
  arrange(header_row)
```

I was met with the following Error: Row and column numbers must be distinct. Perhaps you meant to use a single sheet.

So my first question is how can I go about cleaning up this data for all the sheets?

Also, once I have this data tidied up, is it possible to add new data to each sheet and also apply the vlookup formulas that we have been using within excel?

I understand if I would need to do a vlookup in R, the final output goes into Tableau which reads from the columns that contain the formulas. The goal is to not only automate the new data being added to the file but to also populate the cells that would contain the formulas. Unfortunately, there is PII on my data file so I cannot share. So far I am only looking to tidy up the data that was imported with xlsx_cells. The format within the excel file is basic, as in there are no multiple header rows or offset data.